# How to use old chrome version in rsDriver

Tags: rselenium

```
rsDriver(browser="chrome",port=4450L, chromever="74.0.3729.6")
```

the above command doesn't work since the chrome version mentioned is no longer supported(which used to work before) - since `binman::list_versions("chromedriver")` doesn't list it anymore.
i want to use the older version of chrome - anything before 75. 
Is there any other method?
I also downloaded "74.0.3729.6" driver, but don't know how to use the downloaded driver in rsDriver.

Answer (score 1):

use this code "binman::list_versions("chromedriver")" to see available versions of chrome then add it to rsDriver(chromever = "88.0.0.01") as an example